# Attending a church conference in USA

Tags: visas, usa, zimbabwe

This is my first time in applying for a visitors visa to the USA, I want to attend to a church conference as a visitor.

Can someone please tell me what types of questions will be asked by the consulate, so that I can prepare for the answers? I will be self sponsoring my trip, if that matters.

The conference is in September 2017 -so I have to hurry- and I am from Zimbabwe.

Comment: What types of questions? That's too broad in my opinion.

Comment: @PaulofOsawatomie or an answer could be that one can be asked all kinds of questions. The officers want to test you and see whether you are a genuine visitor corresponding to what you fill in your application. That could mean they ask you about the conference, your life at home and past travels, or whether your family owns a fridge.

Answer (score 1):

There is no set list of questions, but you can expect to be asked why you want to travel to the United States, for how long, where you'll stay, how much it will cost. You may be asked whether you know anyone in the US, who that is and about the relationship. It's not uncommon to explain your home situation, where you've travelled previously, other visas you've had. Your home situation would be explored: what do you do, where are you working, what are you home ties.